# Java code for creating SOAP request from wsdl

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a requirement of creating SOAP request xml for one operation from wsdl(using wsdl url). I am getting a response from a web service call.I need to take some values from this response and add it to another web service Soap request and do a web service call again. So in order to add the new value to the soap request I need to get it's complete soap requst xml.So that's why I was asking how to get soap request xml from wsdl.I cannot use SoapUI since it's dynamic everytime, so I need to write a java code.

I tried using something similar to below code:

```
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject(); 
WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, "<wsdl url>"); 
WsdlInterface wsdl = wsdls[0]; 
for (Operation operation : wsdl.getOperationList()) { 
    WsdlOperation op = (WsdlOperation) operation; 
    System.out.println("OP:"+op.getName()); 
    System.out.println(op.createRequest(true)); 
    System.out.println("Response:"); 
    System.out.println(op.createResponse(true)); 
}
```

but I was getting exception

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fife/ui/rtextarea/RTextArea" in line "WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();

I imported latest jars (soapui-xmlbeans-4.5.0,wsdl-xmlbeans-1.1,soapui-4.5.0) but still throwing exception. Could anybody"http://www.soapui.org/repository/eviware/" suggest how can I rectify it? Is there any other approach which I can take apart from this?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading rsyntaxtextarea-1.0.jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/r/Downloadrsyntaxtextarea10jar.htm add it to your Build Path. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I am getting the same error. Is there any other java code that will help me to get the soap request xml.

Comment: I guess you need to look at some of the tutorials available on net for the same. Have a look at https://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_XML_21days&seqNum=228 as well as http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-soap-handler-example/

Comment: I agree, but I that is for gaining the logic. Here its throwing error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" in line "WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject()" during run time(no issues in complile time), which means it couldn't find the class definition. But I have included all possible jars for this. Is it like it wants jars for the classes and ineterfaces included in it?